# Boot error while booting Ubuntu with USB

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t boot from liveUSB when trying to install it alongside Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197209/cant-boot-from-liveusb-when-trying-to-install-it-alongside-windows-7)

I know this is my 3rd question today, but every other question of mine has been so nicely answered here.. so why not?

Quick story quick, I get Ubuntu on 4gb USB then run the the Ubuntu thing and it restarts my computer so I can boot with USB. I do so, and after I press f12 then go down to USB it says boot error when i press it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind problem fixed. I followed instructions from a different thread comment!

"OS Uninstaller will remove your Windows partition and fix your Grub bootloader.

enter the following int he terminal:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/os-uninstaller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller

The program will install and start, it will look something like this:

Just select Windows Vista in the menu and the click ok.

Click Apply The program will do the rest.

You can read more about OS-Uninstaller HERE

P.S. this is how I removed my Windows 7 from my computer, so I know it works."